# Hive Throwing incorrect header check Error

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am working on a hadoop cluster for evaluation purposes and am using the QWI example found [here](http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/integrating-hadoop-sql-server). I have created my table in Hive as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE qwi2 (
periodicity varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Periodicity of report', 
seasonadj varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Seasonal Adjustment Indicator', 
geo_level varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Geographic level of aggregation', 
geography varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Geography code', 
ind_level varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Industry level of aggregation', 
industry varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Industry code', 
ownercode varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Ownership group code', 
sex varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Gender code', 
agegrp varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Age group code (WIA)', 
race varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: race', 
ethnicity varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: ethnicity', 
education varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: education', 
firmage varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Firm Age group', 
firmsize varchar(256)  COMMENT 'Group: Firm Size group', 
year int  COMMENT 'Time: Year', 
quarter int  COMMENT 'Time: Quarter', 
Emp int  COMMENT 'Employment: Counts', 
EmpEnd int  COMMENT 'Employment end-of-quarter: Counts', 
EmpS int  COMMENT 'Employment stable jobs: Counts', 
EmpTotal int  COMMENT 'Employment reference quarter: Counts', 
EmpSpv int  COMMENT 'Employment stable jobs - previous quarter: Counts', 
HirA int  COMMENT 'Hires All: Counts', 
HirN int  COMMENT 'Hires New: Counts', 
HirR int  COMMENT 'Hires Recalls: Counts', 
Sep int  COMMENT 'Separations: Counts', 
HirAEnd int  COMMENT 'End-of-quarter hires', 
SepBeg int  COMMENT 'Beginning-of-quarter separations', 
HirAEndRepl int  COMMENT 'Replacement hires', 
HirAEndR int  COMMENT 'End-of-quarter hiring rate', 
SepBegR int  COMMENT 'Beginning-of-quarter separation rate', 
HirAEndReplR int  COMMENT 'Replacement hiring rate', 
HirAS int  COMMENT 'Hires All stable jobs: Counts', 
HirNS int  COMMENT 'Hires New stable jobs: Counts', 
SepS int  COMMENT 'Separations stable jobs: Counts', 
SepSnx int  COMMENT 'Separations stable jobs - next quarter: Counts', 
TurnOvrS int  COMMENT 'Turnover stable jobs: Ratio', 
FrmJbGn int  COMMENT 'Firm Job Gains: Counts', 
FrmJbLs int  COMMENT 'Firm Job Loss: Counts', 
FrmJbC int  COMMENT 'Firm jobs change: Net Change', 
FrmJbGnS int  COMMENT 'Firm Gain stable jobs: Counts', 
FrmJbLsS int  COMMENT 'Firm Loss stable jobs: Counts', 
FrmJbCS int  COMMENT 'Firm stable jobs change: Net Change', 
EarnS int  COMMENT 'Employees stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
EarnBeg int  COMMENT 'Employees beginning-of-quarter : Average monthly earnings', 
EarnHirAS int  COMMENT 'Hires All stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
EarnHirNS int  COMMENT 'Hires New stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
EarnSepS int  COMMENT 'Separations stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
Payroll int  COMMENT 'Total quarterly payroll: Sum', 
sEmp int  COMMENT 'Status: Employment: Counts', 
sEmpEnd int  COMMENT 'Status: Employment end-of-quarter: Counts', 
sEmpS int  COMMENT 'Status: Employment stable jobs: Counts', 
sEmpTotal int  COMMENT 'Status: Employment reference quarter: Counts', 
sEmpSpv int  COMMENT 'Status: Employment stable jobs - previous quarter: Counts', 
sHirA int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires All: Counts', 
sHirN int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires New: Counts', 
sHirR int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires Recalls: Counts', 
sSep int  COMMENT 'Status: Separations: Counts', 
sHirAEnd int  COMMENT 'Status: End-of-quarter hires', 
sSepBeg int  COMMENT 'Status: Beginning-of-quarter separations', 
sHirAEndRepl int  COMMENT 'Status: Replacement hires', 
sHirAEndR int  COMMENT 'Status: End-of-quarter hiring rate', 
sSepBegR int  COMMENT 'Status: Beginning-of-quarter separation rate', 
sHirAEndReplR int  COMMENT 'Status: Replacement hiring rate', 
sHirAS int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires All stable jobs: Counts', 
sHirNS int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires New stable jobs: Counts', 
sSepS int  COMMENT 'Status: Separations stable jobs: Counts', 
sSepSnx int  COMMENT 'Status: Separations stable jobs - next quarter: Counts', 
sTurnOvrS int  COMMENT 'Status: Turnover stable jobs: Ratio', 
sFrmJbGn int  COMMENT 'Status: Firm Job Gains: Counts', 
sFrmJbLs int  COMMENT 'Status: Firm Job Loss: Counts', 
sFrmJbC int  COMMENT 'Status: Firm jobs change: Net Change', 
sFrmJbGnS int  COMMENT 'Status: Firm Gain stable jobs: Counts', 
sFrmJbLsS int  COMMENT 'Status: Firm Loss stable jobs: Counts', 
sFrmJbCS int  COMMENT 'Status: Firm stable jobs change: Net Change', 
sEarnS int  COMMENT 'Status: Employees stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
sEarnBeg int  COMMENT 'Status: Employees beginning-of-quarter : Average monthly earnings', 
sEarnHirAS int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires All stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
sEarnHirNS int  COMMENT 'Status: Hires New stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
sEarnSepS int  COMMENT 'Status: Separations stable jobs: Average monthly earnings', 
sPayroll int  COMMENT 'Status: Total quarterly payroll: Sum' 
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/user/lrichards/hive/censusqwi'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

And I have a series of .gz files taken from the Census download server. When I do a simple call like:

```
SELECT *
FROM qw12
LIMIT 100;
```

I get the expected results.

However, when I use the sample query in the URL linked above:

```
SELECT Year, Avg(EarnS)
FROM    qwi2
GROUP BY Year
Order BY Year;
```

I get the following error:

```
INFO : Tez session hasn't been created yet. Opening session
INFO : 

INFO : Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1442592050507_0011)

INFO : Map 1: -/-   Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0/1   Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1)/1   Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1)/1   Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1)/1   Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-1)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-1)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-1)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-2)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-2)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-2)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-3)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-3)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
INFO : Map 1: 0(+1,-3)/1    Reducer 2: 0/6  Reducer 3: 0/1  
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1442592050507_0011_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1442592050507_0011_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:345)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:179)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:167)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:148)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:61)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:350)
... 22 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:345)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:179)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:167)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:148)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:61)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:350)
... 22 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:345)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:179)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:167)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:148)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:61)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:350)
... 22 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:345)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:179)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:167)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:148)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:355)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:137)
at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:61)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.inflateBytesDirect(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor.decompress(ZlibDecompressor.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:91)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:246)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.next(LineRecordReader.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:350)
... 22 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:0, Vertex vertex_1442592050507_0011_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:null]
ERROR : Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 3, vertexId=vertex_1442592050507_0011_1_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:1, Vertex vertex_1442592050507_0011_1_02 [Reducer 3] killed/failed due to:null]
ERROR : Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1442592050507_0011_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:6, Vertex vertex_1442592050507_0011_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:null]
ERROR : DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:2
```

I have tested the files with 7zip and I also have used these same files to deflate and load into SQL for comparison tests between hadoop and SQL. It seems odd that a simple `SELECT` works but another query does not. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It mostly happens of the data is corrupt. The first select statement ran lazily returning only 100 (it didn't read it to the end).

Quick to verify it is by running 'select count(*) from qw12', this will do a table scan.

Comment: Yep. The count query failed as well. Need to figure out why these extracts are failing.

Comment: Okay, this seems a bit odd. All gz files I am pulling from the US Census site are throwing this error in Hive. They do not throw errors extracting on a local Windows machine and the SQL imports are  all successful. Is there something else I need to do on my hadoop cluster?

Comment: Can you share a sample data source that's failing for you?

Comment: The data is from the LEHD QWI data set. A representative files is this one: http://lehd.ces.census.gov/pub/ne/R2015Q3/DVD-sa_fs/qwi_ne_sa_fs_gs_n4_op_u.csv.gz. This file fails on extract and so do any other I pick (for other states, characteristics, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error, although I can read initial few records, but count no. of records failing with same error.

I solved the problem just by renaming my plain (un-compressed) file to .txt. Previously my file name was `<fileName>`; I renamed it to `<fileName>.txt`. Also if you un-compress any file test you can read data from it.

And if you want to test run count number of records as explained above, it will do complete scan which will tell you exactly if data is loaded correctly or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. In my case, some of the files in the hive table had gotten corrupted.

I tried to read the files using the `hdfs -text` command but got the error `text: incorrect header check`

After replacing these corrupt files with the valid ones, the queries started running correctly.

Check the files you have ingested(mostly issue would be with the ones you ingested recently)and see if any of them are corrupt.